# how I transfer data from marklogic to a s3 storage in aws?

Tags: marklogic

how I transfer data from marklogic to a s3 storage in aws?

Comment: The question is slightly confusing. Are you trying to use MarkLogic to access the S3 server?

Comment: Yes ,I want to know that should we do same query  on S3 database as we do in the marklogic  database using rest API.